# Call onComplete() in setCancellable

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am creating an observable by calling `Observable.create`. I want to keep it alive as long as there are subscribers. In this case, `setCancellable` seems to me the only place to call `onComplete()`, or should it be called at all?

```
val data: Observable<Data>
    get() = Observable.create { emitter ->
        val ref = mDatabase.child("users").child("data")
        val listener = ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                emitter.onError(p0.toException())
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                Data.parse(p0)?.let { emitter.onNext(it) }
            }
        })
        emitter.setCancellable { 
            emitter.onComplete() // ???
            ref.removeEventListener(listener)
        } 
    }
```

Comment: It makes no sense to call `onComplete()` upon cancellation and will be ignored anyway.

Comment: So just don't call `onComplete` at all?

Comment: Cancellation is initiated by the consumer telling your source to stop producing alltogether, including terminal events. If your source is otherwise infinite, don't call `onComplete`.